# Code alignment issue in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing a weird issue with android studio. Whenever I enter into a new line ( by pressing enter ) the cursor automatically shifts by two characters. ( See int x=2 line below setContentView )

When I press tab, it aligns with setContentView line.

I have explored almost all preferences of Android Studio and can't figure out a solution. IT is happening since I changed theme to Default from Dracula earlier.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like your whole method is misaligned. Try to automatically re-align:

1. Select all

   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
2. Fix indentation on the selection

   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to keep repeating this process again and again. It should auto-align with the line above when I enter a new line. It looks something needs to be changed in the configurations. Can you suggest anything ?

Comment: @AmitGupta well you can modify the indentation settings in `File` -> `Settings` -> `Code Style` but it should be all configured by default. Try creating a new class and see if your problem persists. A single indent is usually 4 spaces or a TAB, not sure why it indents with 2 spaces on your code.

Comment: Tried that. That actually changes default tab settings but didn't solve my problem.